# Android pending intent to resume app, without starting activity

Tags: android, push-notification, android-pendingintent

Are there any way top resume app from background to foreground without starting activity?

I have 20 activities in my app. When i receive notification i cant know which activity is top now. Can i somehow resume whole app to foreground (not calling some activity with SingleTop,ReoderToTop flags and so on but just move existing app to foreground)?

Answer (score 4):

Your code is far too complicated. You don't need a dummy `Activity`. You should just do what Android does when it launches an app from the HOME screen.

Use a "launch Intent" in your Notification:

```
val intent = getPackageManager().
                    getLaunchIntentForPackage("my.package.name")
```

If your app is already running, this will bring the app to the foreground without creating any new components. If the app is NOT already running, this will start the app by launching the root Activity.

Comment: Thanks for answer, may be i do something wrong but using this method my app is fully restarted from the launching activity even if it is already running.

Comment: You are probably seeing a nasty Android bug. Have you launched your app the first time via the installer or via an IDE (Android Studio)? If so, please kill your app (Settings, apps, force stop) and then restart the app from the HOME screen. Then push to the background and click on your notification and see if the problem is still there.

Comment: Also, please post your manifest in the question, as using special launch modes may also be causing the problem.

Comment: I doubt this is a "nasty Android bug", because I get the same behavior as OP. App starts from the launch activity, not returning where it was last left off. This doesn't work as advertized, or there's some important context missing.

Comment: @JackM please open a new question and describe your problem. Trying to deal with this in comments to another question is not useful or effective.

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution, it may looks weired but it works.

1) Create some dummy activity. This activity will be used as a starting point for pending intent.

```
class DummyPendingIntentActivity:AppCompatActivity()
{
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }
}
```

2) Made this logic in `onCreate` of dummy Activity. In this method you can check are there any activities in stack and resume them if needed, or you can restart your app with starting your 'launcher' activity

```
//Here we check if there any activities in stack
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
{
    if(isTaskRoot)
    {
        //No previous activity running will restart app
        val intent = Intent(this,YourFirstLauncherAcitivity::class.java)
        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
        startActivity(intent)
    }
    else
    {
        //Has some previous activity so will finish to show it
        finish()
    }
}
```

3) Call this dummy start point in any pending intent and you will resume your app or restart it if needed.

```
val intent = Intent(context,DummyPendingIntentActivity::class.java)
val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(AppClass.getApp(), 777, intent, 0)
...
setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently i have faced with issue I had to resume top activity by clicking on push notification while app was in the background. I found this case close to you)

I resolve this issue by saving top activity intent in `onResume()` method of `BaseActivity`, like below:

```
Intent currentActivityIntent = new Intent(this, getClass());
currentActivityIntent.addFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
currentActivityIntent.addFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
App.setCurrentActivityIntent(currentActivityIntent);
```

I get top activity intent after clicking on push.

All you need is to get intent of last top activity with both [flags](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent):
`FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`.